# How to get smooth mouse acceleration?

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, mouse

I have the default NOOBS Debian install. The mouse acceleration seems totally crazy. Well actually, initially it was disabled and the mouse was really slow. I upped the 'Acceleration' and 'Sensitivity' in the settings and it now does accelerate, but the acceleration seems to be binary, i.e. you move the mouse a bit and it's quite slow, but then, once you get past a threshold, it suddenly speeds up.

Is there a way to get a nice smooth acceleration curve like Windows has? (OS X is also pretty awful in this regard.)

Also does anyone know where the code that does the acceleration is, so I can get a look at the algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

Aha I found the answer [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=748412#4) and the actual documentation [here](http://www.x.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/PointerAcceleration/)

Basically a really simple algorithm is used *unless you set the threshold to 0*. I set the acceleration to 2 and it gets pretty close, though it is still far from as good as Windows.

```
xset m 2 0
```

The documentation gives more advanced options for different acceleration profiles (not available in the LXDE GUI). First install xinput:

```
sudo apt-get install xinput
```

Next find your mouse device id:

```
xinput list
```

There should be a mouse there with something like `id=7`. You want the actual mouse device id, not the "Virtual core pointer".

Now get all the settings

```
xinput list-props 7
```

Change the device accel profile from 0 (the default which chooses between polynomial or idiotic depending on whether the threshold is 0 or not). E.g.

```
xinput set-prop 7 "Device Accel Profile" 3
```

Unfortunately I still haven't been able to get it as good as Windows.

Comment: Actually I've been playing with `xset m 8/5 0` all day and I kinda like it, so you've changed my mind a bit ;)  I did edit your post though to stick with the general "no profanity rule".  For future reference questions like are more on topic at [U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).